# streaming large BLOB from database

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, blob

I'm storing large (200mb) files in varbinary(MAX) column. Trying to stream file blob as stated in [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms378813(v=SQL.110).aspx)

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT photo FROM mypics");
rs.next();
InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(2);
```

the problem that it takes rs.next() a "long" time to return, and the bigger file which is loading the longer it returns, so I assuming driver tries to load whole file at once.

Am I missing something? how can I stream large BLOBs from database in more efficient way?

Comment: is the delay really in `rs.next()` not in `rs.getBinaryStream()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you also have to look at the database configuration. I am not a database expert, but I know that working with large blobs could require some tuning on the database side.

So you could tackle this problem from multiple angles as far as I can see.